# start section numbering with 0 not 1 LaTex article class

Tags: sectioning, numbering

In my thesis, my examiners need the section numbering to start with 0 and not from 1.

The structure is somewhat like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{first section}

\subsection{subsection}

\end{document}
```

which gives me result as

> Chapter 1
>
> First
>
> 1.1 first section
>
> 1.1.1 subsection

instead of this I need

> Chapter 1
>
> First
>
> 1.0 first section
>
> 1.0.1 subsection

I tried using

```
\setcounter{section}{-1}
```

before

```
\begin{document}
```

but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every command `\chapter{}` resets your counter section behalf of it. Usually everybody wants to start new numbered sections with 1. You have to change it after the chapters title though. I hope that's explaning it detailed enough?

The following MWE will work for you:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section{first section}

\subsection{subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding \setcounter{section}{-1} before the first section in each chapter solved the problem. Thanks strpeter.